Italian black-and-white movie from the fifties
I'm searching for a movie I saw once, which is as follows: A big city in Italy (Rome?), in the fifties or very early sixties; the movie is in black-and-white. A father comes from some provincial location to visit his son; he knows he will return the following day, and they start experiencing nightlife.
At first, the father is very enthusiastic and undertaking, but he is tired and disenchanted in the end. In the space of one night, he became aware of his age, his life, and the illusion of big-city nightlife.
Any idea what this movie may be?

This is 'episode 5' of the film La Dolce Vita (1960).

5th Night Sequence: Marcello meets his father visiting Rome on the Via Veneto. With Paparazzo, they go to the "Cha-Cha" Club, where Marcello introduces his father to Fanny, a beautiful dancer and one of his past girlfriends (he had promised to get her picture in the paper but failed to do it). Fanny takes a liking to his father. Marcello tells Paparazzo that as a child he had never seen much of his father, who would spend weeks away from home. Fanny invites Marcello's father back to her flat, and two other dancers invite the two younger men to go with them. Marcello leaves the others when they get to the dancers' neighborhood. Fanny comes out of her house, upset that Marcello's father has become ill.
5th Dawn Sequence: Marcello's father has suffered what seems to be a mild heart attack. Marcello wants him to stay with him in Rome so they can get to know each other, but his father, weakened, wants to go home and gets in a taxi to catch the first train to Cesena. He leaves Marcello forlorn, on the street, watching the taxi leave.




